# Login with GOOGLE IN WEBSITE Issue HTTP ERROR 403

Tags: google-plus-signin

Login with google in website shows error "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory or you do not have enough permissions to access the resource"
Please click below link show error message

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsmDR.png)